# Invalid XPath expression: expecting token

Tags: java, xpath

I have the following XML payload:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<product>
  <discount class="standard">
    <id>123</id>
    <beginDate>20181205</beginDate>
    <endDate>20181225</endDate>
  </discount>
  <account>12345</account>
</product>
```

The `class` attribute on the `discount` element can have the following values:

- `standard`
- `special`
- `custom`
- `sale`

I'm trying to write an XPath expression that will match if the has a `product/discount` elemtn with a `class` of one of these values. My best attempt:

```
/product/discount[@class]/[@class = 'standard' or @class = 'special' or @class = 'customer' or @class = 'sale']
```

Produces the following error:

```
InvalidXPathExpression: Invalid xpath: /product/discount[@class]/[@class = 'standard' or @class = 'special' or @class = 'customer' or @class = 'sale']. Reason: javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: A location step was expected following the '/' or '//' token.
```

**Any ideas what is wrong with my XPath?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message indicates, `/` needs to be followed by a location step. Therefore, `/[@class = 'standard' ...]` is not a valid xPath expression.

Instead, try:

```
/product/discount[@class = 'standard' or @class = 'special' or @class = 'customer' or @class = 'sale']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, a shorter XPath 1.0 expression than @jsheeran excellent answer could it be:

```
/product/discount[@class[.='standard' or .='special' or .='customer' or .='sale']]
```

If `class` attribute is a unique token and some special character (like `&#x20;`) cannot be part of it, then you could use this XPath 1.0 *"item IN sequence"* expression:

```
/product
   /discount[
      contains(
         ' standard special customer sale ',
         concat(' ',@class,' ')
      )
   ]
```